# Is it possible to change the height of the jQuery UI datepicker dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Is it possible to change the dropdown height that shows the years in jQuery UI? In the snippet below you can see that when you click the years dropdown, it shows 20 items but it's too long. I could not find a way to shrink this dropdown because the package seem to override everything with JS

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Display month &amp; year menus</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true
    });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```